# Dynamic, mirror table based instance detection

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I'm looking for a way to test if a certain object is of a specific instance. The instances though, are defined in array. So, the lookup becomes kind of dynamic:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('button').item(0);
var instances = ['Attr', 'Element'];
instances.forEach(function(instance)
{
    console.log(element instanceof instance);
});
```

Now, this throws an error:

> `TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<HTMLButtonElement>`.

Okay, then I thought, I could give `eval()` a shot in this case:

```
console.log(element instanceof eval(instance));
```

Which works as expected, but hey, that's an `eval()`!

I'm looking to wrap this in a function, that could be used on whatever objects are out there.

Are there better ways to do this than eval?

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing, you could go by the element's nodeType:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('button').item(0);
var instances = [1, 2]; // nodeType 1 == element, nodeType 2 == attribute
instances.forEach(function(nt)
{
    console.log(element.nodeType == nt);
});
```

[Further infos on node types](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp)

Comment: *I'm looking to wrap this in a function, that could be used on whatever objects are out there.* It's not meant only for DOM Nodes.